# Drools Guvnor and Oracle integration

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I would like to configure Oracle db to Drools Guvnor.

Please let me know how to do this. Any links also will be helpful.

Thanks in anticipation
Bala Krishna.N

Answer (score 2):

In case you still have not figured out, just select *Administration -> Repository Configuration* then enter your connection details. A configuration file will be generated for you. See  [Drools Guvnor manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html/chap-database_configuration.html) for details.